# Textbox for Other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that has multiple groups of radio buttons. When I choose a radio button, it gives output on the same page.

I want to add a radio button for `Other`. When `Other` is selected a textbox should display so the user can enter text.

The user input in the textbox will be displayed on the same sequence.

```js
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function() {
        $("#result").html(function() {
            var str = '';
            $(":checked").each(function() {
                str += $(this).val()+ " ";
            });
            return str;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<table width="100%">
                    <tr>
         <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a1" value="Accomplished" /><label for="accomplished">Accomplished</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a2" value="Exciting" /><label for="exciting">Exciting</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a3" value="Dynamic" /><label for="dynamic">Dynamic</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a4" value="Holistic" /><label for="holistic">Holistic</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a5" value="Animated" /><label for="animated">Animated</label></td>
     </tr>
  </table>

<table width="100%">
                    <tr>
         <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b1" value="CEO" /><label for="ceo">CEO</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b2" value="Account Manager" /><label for="a-manager">Account Manager</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b3" value="Customer Service" /><label for="c-services">Customer Service</label></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b4" value="Project Manager" /><label for="p-manager">Project Manager</label></td>
     </tr></table>
```

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $("#result").html(function() {
        var str = '';
        $(":checked").each(function() {
            str += $(this).val()+ " ";
        });
        return str;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: did you mean you want to add some more radio button..and on click of it you want to achieve what you have mentioned?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want exactly

Comment: can you add mark up and explain more clearly...It would be helpful for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one `<input type="text">` in your other `<td>` and turn it visible whenever user selects the other `<radio>` button. I have it done using CSS. I have made a change in HTML for this: added `other` class to the `<td>`.

```
td.other div.text{
  display: none;
}

td.other input[type=radio]:checked+label + div.text{
  display:block;
}
```

Whenever user selects 'other', it shows the `<input type="text">` to enter the new value. User can see the result in realtime while the user is pressing the keys.

Here is the snippet:

```js
console.clear();

function inputSelected() {
  $("#result").html(function() {
    var str = '';
    $(":checked").each(function() {
      str += $(this).val() + " ";
    });
    return str;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").click(inputSelected);

  $("td.other").click(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').focus();
  });

  $("td.other input[type=text]").keyup(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val().trim();

    if (value.length <= 0) {
      value = 'Other';
    }


    $(this).parent().siblings("input[type=radio]").val(value);
    $(this).parent().siblings("label").html(value);

    inputSelected();

  })
});

//$(".other label").click();
```

```css
td.other div.text {
  display: none;
}
td.other input[type=radio]:checked+label + div.text {
  display: block;
}
td.other input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Jquery: Add new radio field for selection">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a1" value="Accomplished" />
        <label for="a1">Accomplished</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a2" value="Exciting" />
        <label for="a2">Exciting</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a3" value="Dynamic" />
        <label for="a3">Dynamic</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a4" value="Holistic" />
        <label for="a4">Holistic</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a5" value="Animated" />
        <label for="a5">Animated</label>
      </td>
      <td class="other">
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" id="a6" value="Other" />
        <label for="a6">Other</label>
        <div class="text">
          <input type="text" id="other1" value="Other">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b1" value="CEO" />
        <label for="b1">CEO</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b2" value="Account Manager" />
        <label for="b2">Account Manager</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b3" value="Customer Service" />
        <label for="b3">Customer Service</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b4" value="Project Manager" />
        <label for="b4">Project Manager</label>
      </td>
      <td class="other">
        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup2" id="b5" value="Other">
        <label for="b5">Other</label>
        </input>
        <div class="text">
          <input type="text" id="other2" value="Other">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="result">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this snippet, I have updated the `for` in `<label>` to refer to the `<radio>`.

Comment: this answer is quite good but i am looking for a script that instantly show text whatever i type on other radio button... mean like i select a radio button of accomplished and it show accomplished below....same when i  type anything for other option it should be display without pressing enter. Hope you can help me to get exact script for such input :)

Comment: @AminaMalik Yes, that can be achieved. So, do you also want a new radio button for your new option? Or, do you want to modify 'other' into new option?

Comment: i want to modigy 'other'into new option that will submit input detail same as radio button do like a radio for other option....

Comment: @AminaMalik I have updated the snippet. User can modify the 'other'. Try it once.

Comment: it works thanks alot for such a nice help.... :)

Comment: Now i just create another option for search such adjectives from google that is <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."> , so i'll be able to find suitable adjectives and put them to the other radio button...kindly let me know which script i can use to search adjectives only... i applied some google script but they also show non-adjective options.....Hope you will help me for this also :) Waiting for your soon reply thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AminaMalik You can create your own list of adjectives and provide hint to users while they are typing. And, maybe you can find more better answer, if you ask this as a question in SO. If you ask that question, share the link to that new question here.

Comment: @AminaMalik if your above asked question is answered, and you found that helpful, don't forget to upvote and mark that as an answer. thanks. :)

Comment: I already vote for your answer :)

And again thanks for the advice

Comment: here is link of new discussion...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745589/javascript-jquery-for-search-box